# Adding some data onto distinct query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which i would like to aggregate, making a specific field distinct but also adding other field data to that aggregated result. Below is an example of my collection

```
   {
        "_id": ObjectId("57d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579"),
        "_class": "hbservlet.FinalSubmissions",
        "active": true,
        "mappedTracks": 
        [
            { "position": 0, "title": "01. Ain't No Time.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr157d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
            { "position": 1, "title": "02. In Her Mouth.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr257d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
            { "position": 2, "title": "03. Maybach.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr357d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" }
        ],
        "createdBy": ObjectId("57d6bb99b17ee01a5427af08"),
        "userId": ObjectId("57d6bb99b17ee01a5427af08"),
        "artistname": "test",
    }, {
        "_id": ObjectId("14d6bc99ebc942fc13cf9579"),
        "_class": "hbservlet.FinalSubmissions",
        "active": false,
        "mappedTracks": [
            { "position": 0, "title": "partysong.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr114d6bc99ebc942fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
            { "position": 1, "title": "outside", "url": "/published/music/tr214d6bc99ebc942fc13cf9579_.aac" },],
        "createdBy": ObjectId("57d6bb99b17ee01a5427af08"),
        "userId": ObjectId("57d6bb99b17ee01a5427af08"),
        "artistname": "mynameismyname",
    }
```

i use the distinct query (db.published.distinct("mappedTracks")) to gather all the mappedTracks so i get this

```
{ "position": 0, "title": "01. Ain't No Time.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr157d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
{ "position": 1, "title": "02. In Her Mouth.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr257d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
{ "position": 2, "title": "03. Maybach.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr357d6bc99e4b014fc13cf9579_.aac" },
{ "position": 0, "title": "partysong.mp3", "url": "/published/music/tr114d6bc99ebc942fc13cf9579_.aac" }, 
{ "position": 1, "title": "outside", "url": "/published/music/tr214d6bc99ebc942fc13cf9579_.aac" }
```

this is the result i want but i would also like to add the _id, userID, artistname of which document it belongs, to the new object created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) operator [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
          {$unwind:"$mappedTracks"}, 
          {$group:{_id:
                       {mappedTracks:"$mappedTracks", 
                        id:"$_id", 
                        userId:"$userId", 
                        artistname:"$artistname"
                        }
                   }
           }
])
```

Please note that this is assuming that now you would like a distinct value combination of all those four fields. If you would like only distinct on `mappedTracks` you have to decide what to do on duplicate values of `userId` and `artistname`. If this is the case, see [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator to use the first value in case of duplicates.

See also aggregation operator [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) if you would like to rename some fields after `$group`.

If this query is a frequently used query for your use case, I would recommend to reconsider your [Data Modelling or Document Structure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/).

Comment: Thanks wan, This pointed my in the correct direction. I'm reconsidering my document structure for a more efficient system.